# How do I make a form submit only for the word of my choosing

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I have a login page.  I want the form to validate the form to allow the form to submit if I only enter a specif word for the username and a different word, of my choosing, for the password.  I do not wish to use a sql database.  I want it to validate to a specific word that I pre-set it to. If it is right I would like it to redirect me to my index.htm page once I hit submit.  But if it is wrong I would like it to clear the text fields.  What code do I use to do this. Here is a basic layout of my code:

html

```
<body>
<h1 class="color">Login</h1>
<form action="index.htm">
<span class="heading">Username:</span><br>

<input name="username" type="text" id="username" size="20">
<br>
<span class="heading">Password:</span><br>
<input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="10"><br>


<button name="Login" type="submit" onclick = "evaluateInput()">Login</button>

</form>
</body>
```

js

```
evaluateInput = function(){
     inputBox = document.getElementById("username");
     if(inputBox.value == "<insert password here>"){

     }else

     }
 }{
     inputBox = document.getElementById("password");
     if(inputBox.value == "<insert password here>"){

     }else

     }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please see [ask] for information on what makes a good question. Right now, the question is probably too broad to fit in at Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have tried using javascript to check if the text fields match with the word of my chose, but then I am not able to redirect to index.htm page after i hit submit

Comment: Please edit your question and add the JavaScript code you have tried so far.

Comment: Ther is my java script, but I dont know what to put in the if and else statments so that if the username and password is correct it will submit or else it will clear the fields.

Answer (score 0):

If you succeed form validation as commented out above, you can use below code to redirect.

```
window.location.href = "index.html"
```

**EDIT**

```
evaluateInput = function(){
    inputUsername = document.getElementById("username");
    inputPassword = document.getElementById("password");
    if(inputUsername.value == "<insert username here>" && inputPassword.value == "<insert password here>"){
        window.location.href = "index.html"
    }
 }
```

Comment: I want it not to redirect if the username and password is wrong.  It would be nice if it could clear the text fields.

Comment: it redirects if username and password are both true. I think you can find the solution from here.

Comment: When I hit submit it goes to the index page even if the username and password are nor correct because the action for the form is index.htm and if I remove it, it wont redirect.